# bufferCount on a list of objects - 10er packages not working

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I want the 400 objects from the API not at once, but in arrays in 10er groups.
console --> [10objects in here], [another 10 ], and so on until the 400 objects are done with instead of on array with all 400 of them to be loaded at once.

```
export class AppComponent {
  data: any;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
      .bufferCount(10, 10)
      .subscribe(x => {
        console.log(x)
      }
}
```

The code gives me an array containing 500 objects from the API.
Like so:[image]

I want it like this:
(10)[{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}]
(10)[{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}] ...

Comment: Please clarify yur question. What does "Want: [10objects]" mean?

Comment: Does the code you've shared work? What does it do if it's not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
      // missing piece - emits them one by one
      .mergeAll()
      .bufferCount(10,10)
      .subscribe(x => {
        console.log(x)
      }
      )
  }
}
```

mergeAll emits the objects one by one
bufferCount can then bundle them in 10er groups